# Delphi Xe6 Component package issue

Tags: delphi, custom-component, delphi-xe6

I have a component pack that has been working great for a few years. I currently am trying to produce both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

I build debug and release win32 versions with no error.

I build the win64 version with no error.

But when I try to build the win64 release version I get **"[dcc64 Fatal Error] FBCComponents.dpk(31): E2202 Required package 'rtl' not found"**

Does anyone have any idea what is happening...

TIA Farley

Comment: There is no 64-bit version of components for design-time. The IDE is 32-bit only, so there are no 64-bit component installs for components. You can't build and install 64-bit design-time packages into the 32-bit IDE.

Comment: Thanks but that still does not resolve the issue with the win64 runtime. Am I still not understanding?

Comment: I don't have any issue with building Win64 runtime libraries (in fact, I just ported a large third-party library today because the vendor hasn't done it yet). What version of Delphi were your components last successfully installed/compiled by?

Comment: Ken is saying the same thing I'm saying in my answer. Did you read it? You need to separate your code into two different packages.

Comment: Why do you want to build 64 bit packages at all? Do you really release applications that use runtime packages? I for one don't, I compile everything into the executable(s) and be done with it. No package required. (Of course that doesn't answer your question either.)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to divide these apart into two separate packages - `runtime` and `designtime`. The design-time package is only responsible for installing into the IDE.

Now, a design-time package works directly with the IDE. The Delphi IDE is 32bit only. So, the design-time package must also be 32bit only - whereas the run-time package should be compiled for whatever platforms are desired.